# Ruby hash initialization: is this niftyness possible?

Tags: ruby, hash

This code works, of course:

```
@x = { :all => { :x => 1, :y => 2 } }
```

But this doesn't:

```
@x = { :abc, :all => { :x => 1, :y => 2 } }
```

Is there any way to do what I want here?  i.e. I want two keys in a hash to each refer to the same (copy of a) value.  But I only want to specify the value once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, here:

```
@x = { :all => tmp = { :x => 1, :y => 2 }, :abc => tmp }
```

Comment: That's not a copy though, but you can fix that by using tmp.dup (shallow copy)

Comment: True. I interpreted "the same copy of a value" as meaning one instance.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
@x = { :all => tmp = { :x => 1, :y => 2 }, :abc => tmp.reject {|k,v| false} }
```